Why does passing an instance of \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile to a custom cast result in an infinite loop?
I have a Configuration model in which I have implemented a custom cast, the getter works perfectly but let's look at the setter.
For clarity, I have trimmed down the code samples to only what's relevant to the context.
App/Models/Configuration.php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Configuration extends Model
{ 
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'value' => \App\Casts\ConfigValue::class,
        ];
    }
}

App/Casts/ConfigValue.php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class ConfigValue implements CastsAttributes
{ 
    public function set(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes): mixed
    { 
        $saveable = $value instanceof UploadedFile || 
                     (isset($value[0]) && $value[0] instanceof UploadedFile);

        echo 1; // Take note of this

        return match (true) {
            ...// Other conditions
            $saveable => $this->doUpload(UploadedFile|array $value),
            ...// Other conditions
            default => (string) $value,
        };
    }
}

Let's also not bother about the logic for the file uploads, the problem here is that X-Debug throws an infinite loop error after terminating the script when proccessing the upload. But if I straight out return the output, you can see from the image below that the script is run several times before it returns the response, adding upload logic to this ends us in an infinite loop.

App/Controllers/ConfigController.php
$config = Configuration::where('key', $key)->first();

$config->value = $value;
$config->save();

On the Controller $key and $value are from a foreach loop of $request->configurations, the above works well when $value is anything but an instance of \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile in which case we fall into the infinite loop.
What am I doing wrong here?

The infinite loop occurs because your custom cast's set method is causing recursive calls to itself when handling an instance of UploadedFile.

@JeyhunRashidov do you have any suggested solutions? I came up with a workaround that required me to do the upload outside of the cast which isn't the ideal solution for my use case.
